# Does my Public IP address change even if I didn't restart my PC?

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, webserver

So I want to know that can I build a website by only port forwarding my local host Apache server?

And will It be accessible by my Public IP address (the one in whatismyipaddress.com)?

And lastly, will it ever change even if I didn't restart my PC (or gone offline)?

Comment: This entirely depends on the configuration of your ISP.  They have complete and total control over your ip address lease.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I check it? (what configuration should they have?)

Comment: Ask your ISP for a static IP address. Most offer it for a small fee. Note that self hosting like this is likely to be insecure. You can find cheap or free shared hosting instead.

Comment: @anotherfred Is there an ISP that gives a free static IP to all of there client?

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in having a constant way of being found from the general internet, you may consider using a service like https://dyndns.org. This provides an address (like mywebsite.dyndns.org) that will be translated to an IP address when a host looks up the address.

Comment: This will only work if the ISP offers a public IP directly to the clients, which isn't the case for most fibre and LTE connections - they usually use a [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).